# Run ./configure from bash script fails due "error: cannot compute suffix of object files"

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-errors, configure

I'm trying to automate some stage of compile/build on Linux RHEL7 host using a bash script, but when i try to use ./configure it fails due to :

```
configure:3793: error: in `/app/compiling/BUILD_AREA/TEST/SRC/zabbix-4.2.6':
configure:3795: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
```

using :

```
CC="gcc"
PATH="/app/app_lib/mysql/bin:/app/app_lib/bin:/app/app_lib/build-1:/app/app_lib:$PATH"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/app/app_lib:/app/app_lib/include:/app/app_lib/lib:/app/apache/modules:/app/app_lib/ssl:/app/app_lib/lib/iconv:/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/lib:/app/ap_lib/mysql/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

export CC
export PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

ARG_ZABBIX="--prefix=/app/zabbix --datarootdir=/app/zabbix/share --docdir=/app/zabbix/share/doc/$PKGAPPDIR --enable-agent --enable-ipv6 --enable-java --enable-server --includedir=/app/zabbix/include --libdir=/app/zabbix/lib --mandir=/app/zabbix/share/man/$PKGAPPDIR --with-libcurl=/app/app_lib/bin/curl-config --with-libxml2=/app/app_lib/bin/xml2-config --with-mysql=/app/mysql/bin/mysql_config --with-net-snmp=/app/app_lib/bin/net-snmp-config --with-openipmi=/app/app_lib --with-ssh2=/app/app_lib"
CONFIGURE="configure"

cd /app/compiling/BUILD_AREA/TEST/SRC/zabbix-4.2.6
"./${CONFIGURE}" "${ARG_ZABBIX}" 2>&1
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> Any help would be really appreciated!

Find the respective `config.log` (like the one in `$(builddir)/gcc`) and have a look.  Some configure tests might fail as configure is querying availability of host features; the relevant fail is usually recorded at the end of the relevant `config.log`.

A common cause for this error is that the target [Binutils](https://sourceware.org/binutils/) (`as`, the assembler) cannot be found as configure is trying to find out what suffix to use for object files.  Or host `as` is used where actually the target `as` (as of `--target=`) should be used, and the host `as` throws a syntax error because it is fed with target assembly.

> ./configure

GCC does [not support configuring in the source directory](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) or any of its sub-folders:

> *"First, we **highly** recommend that GCC be built into a separate directory from the sources which does **not** reside within the source tree."*

Comment: In config.log I see :  configure:3775: gcc -c  -I conftest.c >&5
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3779: $? = 4
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "Zabbix"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "zabbix"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "4.2.6"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "Zabbix 4.2.6"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "zabbix"
| #define VERSION "4.2.6"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| int
| main ()
| {
|
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }

Comment: configure:3795: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details

Comment: Is that uppercase `I` in `-I`  in `gcc -c -I conftest.c`?

Comment: Yes is "-I" : seems strange that ./configure in same path outside bash script with the same ENV it completes successfully

Comment: `-I` is to be followed by an include path, which `conftest.c` is not.  Presumably, some shell variable that's supposed to hold the path is empty for whatever reason.  Maybe you can figure out the respective lines of `configure.ac` that were expanded to this specific `configure` test and find which shell / configure variable is void.